# Multiple Ubercart? Trying to do a multi-seller site.

Tags: ubercart

Hello Drupal community. I'm trying to create a seller's site. This is what it needs to do:

A seller will have his own system in which customers can buy him directly.

The products that the seller will sell will be in common from all the sellers. But each seller will need to be able to set his own price.

I found ubercart (I found it amazing!!!), and it does much more than I'm asking for. I would like to know what should I do? Write a module from scratch? Extend Ubercart? Is there a multiple ubercart possibility?

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: This question might be a bit too broad to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Marketplace](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace).

The modern alternative to ubercart is [commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) and there is a [marketplace](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace) module too, though it's still in beta.

Comment: Thanks a million! I think I'll be going with commerce's marketplace since it's Drupal 7 version is on Beta!

Comment: I talked to the maintainer of the Commerce Marketplace module, and he said it is not currently stable, and will take about two to three weeks of solid, dedicated work until it reaches that point.

I would use Ubercart for now, as much as Commerce looks to be the better solution long-term.